# How to change aws_instance with user_data value in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an `aws_instance` in a `terraform` file, and I want to tag this instance with a value within my `user_data` script.

How can I tag my `instance` with a value of `LOGINTOKEN` in the `user_data` script?

Example:

```
resource "aws_instance" "my_instance" {  
  ami = "some_ami"
  instance_type = "some_instance"
  //other configs                

  user_data = <<EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    LOGINTOKEN=$(echo { "token": "qwerty12345" } | docker run --rm -i stedolan/jq -r .token)
    EOF
  tags {
    LoginToken = "$LOGINTOKEN"
  }
}
```

Comment: You will need to write something using the AWS CLI. Retrieve Instance ID from the metadata service and update the tags of that instance, you will need to give adequate IAM permissions to the instance however.

Comment: It's not particularly clear what the problem is from the example. If you know what you are putting in your tag and user data script at run time then this is straight forward. Are you saying you want to take a result from running the user data script to then update the tag on the instance?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Exactly,  I changed the question

Comment: It might also help if your worked example also had something dynamic in the user data script that you wanted in the tag instead of something that you know before hand. Something like `uname -r` would be something that the instance would be able to know but Terraform wouldn't (unless it was exposed by an AMI tag or something).

Comment: Done.. I want to put the LOGINTOKEN into a tag in my instance